# Creating a dataframe with groupby

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new data frame in which some columns are grouped by, and some of the original columns are included within the new data frame.

For example:
Trying to group the total sales per month for different products and used the code:

```
sales2 = sales.groupby(['products', 'date', 'month']).sum(['count_of_sales'])
```

However, I want to include the original product and month columns within the new data frame sales2. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi, I was able to solve for it using reset.index()

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add new column in the dataframe as normally we do:

```
sales2['Original Product'] = sales['Product']
sales2['Month'] = sales['Month']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this either with:

```
sales2 = sales.groupby(['products', 'date', 'month'], 
                        as_index = False).sum(['count_of_sales'])
```

Which will keep them as columns or:

```
sales2 = sales.groupby(['products', 'date', 'month']).sum(['count_of_sales'])
sales2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)
```

which will turn the indexes into columns.